# How can I get the correct client.pem file on a bootstrapped Windows Azure VM?

Tags: azure, chef, knife

I'm really struggling to bootstrap a Windows VM in Azure using knife azure.   I have my image and I've created the winrm firewall rule and configured winrm per the instructions.   The machine spins up and the bootstrap connection starts, but the client fails to authenticate to the server.

The client does install and the proper validator.PEM file is there, but the c:\chef\client.pem doesn't authenticate correctly.   How do I correct this?

(I'm SOOOOOOOO close to success on this it's just eating away at me.  :) )

Comment: The client.pem file is created after the client connects successfully to the Chef Server. For the first connection you either need real SSL certificate (not self-signed) on the Chef Server, or setting in client.rb: `ssl_verify_mode :verify_none`. As for how to get that client.rb on to the newly created server I don't know - I've struggled with this same problem for the past several days. For now I settled to use hosted Chef Server at https://manage.chef.io and it seems to work with knife azure.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this fixed? Have you tried just using the Chef vm extension that is built into azure? With knife azure you specify the "--bootstrap-protocol cloud-api" to use the VM extension.